# filter out info in nginx log_format

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-log

I want to log the `$request` coming in but want to filter out sensitive information such as passwords or keys.

I tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
http {
  log_format xxx '$filtered_request';

  location /xxx {
    set $filtered_request $request;
    if ($filtered_request ~ (.*)password=[^&]*(.*)) {
      set $filtered_request $1password=****$2;
    }

    access_log /var/log/xxx.log xxx;
  }
}
```

This saves empty lines to the log file.

In fact, the following doesn't work either:

```
http {
  log_format yyy '$yyy';

  location /foo {
    set $yyy 'abc';
    access_log /var/log/yyy.log yyy;
  }
}
```

The result is still empty lines.

How to use custom variables in `log_format`?

I'm using nginx/1.2.5

UPDATE: I notice that the `set $yyy 'abc';` actually does something, but the value is not reflected in the log. i.e.:

```
http {
  log_format yyy '$request $arg_password';
  location /foo {
    set $arg_password 'filtered';
    access_log /var/log/yyy.log yyy;    
  }
}
```

The `$arg_password` becomes empty with the `set ...` statement, and log the arg `?password=asdf` as `asdf` if the `set ...` statement is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there are some rewrite going on in that location:

```
location /foo {
  ...
  rewrite ^(/foo)... ... break;

  set $filtered_request $request;
  ...
}
```

If I move the `set` statements before the rewrite, it works fine:

```
location /foo {
  ...

  set $filtered_request $request;
  ...

  rewrite ^(/foo)... ... break;

  ...
}
```

Doesn't know why it had the side effect of making the variable empty.
But at least the problem at hand is solved.